# Xamari: RecyclerView sometimes just loads a completely wrong item. Am I maybe using it wrong?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

in my app, there is a recyclerview with many songs in it. about 600 of them. If a users presses a song, it is supposed to play. Simple as that. HOWEVER,
and absolutely random occasions the recyclerview just loads a completely different song than the one I pressed on. Once this happens, it will happen more and more often during the use of the app. So say, the first 20 clicks, everything is fine, it occurs on click 21, then 22, then 23 and 24 are fine again, then 26 is bad, 27 is good and so on.

I am getting the position of the click via "AdapterPosition" which is a get from the recyclerview, and with a toast message, I checked that always the right position is being returned. However, even though the click returns the right position, some random song is being played and the position is being ignored. I really wish you guys can help me out here. This is the strapped down version of my 2 classes:

The PhotoAlbum Adapter:

```
public class PhotoAlbumAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    public List<MP3objectSmall> mp3Obj;
    Context ctx;
    Activity act;
    MediaMetadataRetriever reader;
    DataBase db;
    List<SeekObj> seekObj;
    Typeface tf;

    public static Android.Net.Uri NewSongUri = null;
    public static Android.Net.Uri OldSongUri = null;

    public PhotoAlbumAdapter(List<MP3objectSmall> mp3Obj, Context ctx, DataBase db, List<SeekObj> seekObj, Activity act)
    {
        this.mp3Obj = mp3Obj;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.db = db;
        this.seekObj = seekObj;
        this.act = act;
        reader = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

        tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(ctx.Assets, "Baiti.ttf");
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
                    Inflate(Resource.Layout.CardView, parent, false);
        PhotoViewHolder vh = new PhotoViewHolder(itemView, mp3Obj, act, reader, db, seekObj, ctx);
        return vh;
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        PhotoViewHolder vh = holder as PhotoViewHolder;

        try
        {
            reader.SetDataSource(mp3Obj[position].Mp3Uri);
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        string SongName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyTitle);
        string ArtistName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyArtist);


        vh.SongName.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        vh.AristName.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        vh.SongName.Text = SongName;
        vh.AristName.Text = ArtistName;
    }

    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get { return mp3Obj.Count(); }
    }

}
```

The PhotoViewHolder:

```
    public class PhotoViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView Image { get; private set; }
        public TextView SongName { get; private set; }
        public LinearLayout lnContainer { get; private set; }
        public TextView AristName { get; private set; }
        private List<MP3objectSmall> mp3Obj;
        Context ctx;
        Activity act;
        MediaMetadataRetriever reader;
        DataBase db;
        List<SeekObj> seekObj;
        private static MP3object ObjectToBeSaved;
        private static bool FirstStart = true;

        public PhotoViewHolder(View itemView, List<MP3objectSmall> mp3Obj, Activity act, MediaMetadataRetriever reader, DataBase db, List<SeekObj> seekObj, Context ctx) : base(itemView)
        {
            // Locate and cache view references:
            SongName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);
            AristName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
            lnContainer = itemView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linlay_cardview);

            this.mp3Obj = mp3Obj;
            this.act = act;
            this.reader = reader;
            this.db = db;
            this.seekObj = seekObj;
            this.ctx = ctx;

            lnContainer.Click += delegate
            {
                int pos = AdapterPosition;
                ClickEvent(pos, AristName.Text, SongName.Text);
                //Toast.MakeText(ctx, pos.ToString() + AristName.Text + SongName.Text, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            };
        }

        private void ClickEvent(int position, string artist, string song)
        {

            if(PhotoAlbumAdapter.NewSongUri != null)
            {
                PhotoAlbumAdapter.OldSongUri = PhotoAlbumAdapter.NewSongUri;
            }

            PhotoAlbumAdapter.NewSongUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(mp3Obj[position].Mp3Uri);

            if (!FirstStart) // dont save the very first uri, only get it for playing 
            {
                ObjectToBeSaved = WriteMetaDataToFileList(PhotoAlbumAdapter.OldSongUri.ToString());
            }

            Activity_Player.CurrentSongObject = WriteMetaDataToFileList(PhotoAlbumAdapter.NewSongUri.ToString());
            Activity_Player.txt_CurrentSong.Text = song;
            Activity_Player.txt_CurrentArtist.Text = artist;

            PlayMusic(PhotoAlbumAdapter.NewSongUri);

            FirstStart = false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Bad code style,could you obey google's java programming specification in your code style,it's really read hardly.

Comment: hi, this isnt java. it is c#.

Comment: sorry about that,I didn't see carefully,I'm very sorry.

Comment: @innomotionmedia - Try overriding this method         `public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }`